# Git fetch/merge doesn't work

Tags: git

I made some changes to the code.

- git add -A
- git commit -m ".."
- git push origin master

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
>   to push some refs to '.....' To prevent you from losing history,
>   non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes before
>   pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git
>   push --help' for details.

- git fetch origin master

> remote: Counting objects: 42, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>   (26/26), done. remote: Total 26 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), done. From ......  * branch
>   master     -> FETCH_HEAD

- git merge master

> Already up-to-date.

- git merge origin/master

> Already up-to-date.

- git merge origin/master master

> Already up-to-date. Yeeah!

- git push origin master

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
>   to push some refs to '....' To prevent you from losing history,
>   non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes before
>   pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git
>   push --help' for details.

So the same again.

What's going on? With git pull it works, but I read it's better to use fetch/merge, so please tell me  what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git pull` will lead to exactly the same result as a `git fetch` and `git merge`.

`git fetch` works a bit different depending how you call it.
Usually you just call `git fetch`. This will update all remote branches from origin.
Afterwards your own branch is still `master` while the remote branch is `origin/master`, hence if you want to merge `origin/master` into `master` you have to checkout `master` and `git merge origin/master`.

`git fetch origin master` will just fetch that one branch and store it into a temporary branch called FETCH_HEAD. you could merge it using `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

But you probably only want to do a simple `git pull`. ;)

Hint: use `git branch -av` to see all your local and remote branches.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Say I use git fetch and it will update 3 branches. branch1, branch2, branch3, now I only want to merge branch1 and branch3. (merge each branch to it's origin, not together). How do I do that?

Comment: `git checkout master; git merge origin/branch1; git merge origin/branch3` - a merge will always merge the given branch into the current one, hence you just just merge the first and then the second. you can also merge both at the same time with `git merge origin/branch1 origin/branch3`.

Answer (score 1):

What branch do you have checked out?  `git merge origin/master master` does not target `master`:  You always merge to the current branch.

Comment: I'm in the master branch. I was just trying all combinations in fact :D. So, how to do it properly?